# How to control Dropbox in GNOME3?

Tags: dropbox, gnome3, fedora-21

The [Dropbox website](https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/desktop/change-preferences) indicates that, to change settings, you click the icon in the system tray:

[image: Dropbox icon in system tray]

I'm running GNOME3 (Fedora 21) which has no system tray. Where can I find the Dropbox icon?

Specifically, I want to log-out, and log back in as a different user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the bottom of the screen , there is a bar system that is hidden and displayed. When you click on the button in the upper left corner and all windows are deployed , you have to move the mouse down the screen

Comment: Note that this no longer applies in GNOME 3.16, which ships with Fedora 22.  There is now a sliding tray in the bottom-left corner for "old-style" notification icons: http://fedoramagazine.org/fedora-22-workstation-new-notifications/

Comment: Note, as of 2017 the system tray doesn't exist anymore (I'm on Gnome 3.26.2, but IIRC it was removed in previous versions already).